# Overlaping RecyclerView Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I want to know if is possible create an overlapping recyclerview like the following:

[image]

I've tried ItemDecorations and stack views, but I'm not getting the expected result.

Comment: Use frame layout. Just add recycler view and the other view inside frame layout, make sure the code for other item must be below recycler view.

Comment: Look for something like `CardStackLayoutmanager` or `StackLayoutmanager`.